# How to rasterize a vector data with style

Tags: style, c++, rasterization

I want to make a utility in c++ which can rasterize vector data with some specified style. I know about gdal_rasterize. But the problem with it is, we cannot specify the style details. Do we have a library using which i can make this utility? If no libraries available then what is the best method to do the same?

Thanks in Advance